# Is it appropriate to call the circular edges of a cylinder "corners"?

Tags: geometry

I recently corrected someone when they were describing a machining operation on a lathe. They referred to the circular edge of a cylinder as a "corner" and I got confused.

Then, thinking more about this, I realized that maybe it is indeed a corner mathematically speaking and maybe they have a better intuition about geometry than I do.

Comment: I don't believe I've ever heard the term "corner" applied this way, but it certainly makes sense in the context of lathework: to the lathe, a cylinder is a spinning rectangle, the *corners* of which trace the cylinder's circular edges.

Comment: This appears to be a question about the English language, not about mathematics.  (There could be a mathematical question if you are asking about a technical definition of "corner" in mathematics, but that doesn't seem to be what you have in mind, given your reference to "intuition about geometry".  In any case, "corner" does not usually have any precise meaning in math.)

Comment: Mathematical definitions and colloquial definitions are rarely the same. Language is a socially constructed and mathematical definitions are as popular as mathematics, which isn't very popular. I think if you asked most people what a circle is they couldn't tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ambiguity of the term 'corner' is why we tend not to use it in mathematics. Instead we talk about 'vertices' and 'edges'. A cylinder does not have any vertices, but it does have two edges.

Before deciding whether it is mathematically appropriate to call the edge a 'corner' you would have to define in terms of mathematics what you mean by a corner. Once you have done that, you could then start deciding whether or not the edge is a corner. Until then the question has no mathematical answer.